# How to make a jelly material?

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to create a jelly bear in Blender, but I don't know how to set the specific parameters. Does anyone know how to make a jelly material?

Comment: Is it a texture for the mesh or a material so you can render an image of the bear?

Comment: I think I mixed the conception here, sorry:P  I mean how to create a jelly material ball in Cycles Render or Blender Render. Thank you for the replying.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  For what it's worth, "jelly" may not be a very good descriptor because there are two many things which use that as a name, which look very different. Petroleum jelly, for example, is and opaque, yellowish semi-solid, while raspberry jelly is transparent (or semi-transparent), and has a different appearance altogether. Question 15355 "resources-for-blender" has a list of sites with a large number of materials, one or more of which will be, if not exactly, then at least close to what you need.

Comment: Wow, these resources are sufficient, just what I need, thank you very much :3

Comment: You should add more details of what you have tried.

Comment: For the record: IMO this is *not* a duplicate of the resources question. This question is asking how to make a material, not asking for resources. [Even if one of the answers on the resources question answered this question it doesn't make this any more of a duplicate](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/549/599).

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean a gummy bear.  To do this I used Cycles and added a Glass Shader and Glossy Shader together with a Mix Shader.  I also added a transluscent shader with a second mix shader.  The light in the rendered picture is coming form the ground plane.

[image: Cycles Nodes]

[image: Rendered Cube(Light is Coming from the Ground Plane)]