# I want to create a character like a cartoonish jelly

Tags: modeling

I want to create a character like a cartoonish jelly. But I don't know where to start from. I am a debutant in blender. I want to create a character like this one :

[image]

Can you help me please ! Thanks !

Comment: Hello m4thus4n, the shapes are pretty basic, I've tried to find a material as similar as possible, check here: https://zupimages.net/up/20/23/ipky.jpg

Comment: @moonboots, wow, can you share full file? it's really beautiful

Comment: sure: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=71rMMSNR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/71rMMSNR/)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32466/how-to-make-a-jelly-material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- learn how to create basic shapes
- learn how to edit basic shapes (resize, stretch, proportional edit)
- optional: learn how to sculpt
- learn how to use node shaders to create this glass effect
- learn how to set up the render process

It will be a long journey, but you'll have a lot of fun

Comment: Agreed. Start where a lot of us did - do the donut tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!